# OAoth Magic function Error

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I am using OAuth Class which have fucntion

```
class OAuth {
            public __construct ( string $consumer_key , string $consumer_secret [, string $signature_method = OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1 [, int $auth_type = 0 ]] )

           public bool enableDebug ( void )
           public array getRequestToken ( string $request_token_url [, string $callback_url ] )

           }
```

I am calling these like this

```
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
}
```

giving error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '__construct' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

And Error for disableDebug

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'bool' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

Please help what is the problem

Comment: Are you sure you fetched the `OAuth` class for PHP and not for some other language? The class code is far away from being valid PHP code.

Comment: I am using this one class http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php

Comment: Jürgen Thelen I believe that you can fix my problem . Actually I want to display products from Magento store to use Magento Rest Api.
Please help me to solve this metter. I am pulling my hair from 4 days.

Comment: Ah, now I see^^. You've copy/pasted that directly from this page and thought it's an ordinary class. Well, it's **not**. It's an **extension** that needs to be installed/compiled in your PHP, before you can use it.

Comment: Can u help me how I will able to access Magento Products at my webpage through Magento Rest Api. Thanks
I am using example code but problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542947/get-magento-product-feed-using-mangento-rest-api-but-oauth-error